# BigQuery filter using LEFT OUTER JOIN or Anti-join

Tags: google-bigquery

I can think of 2 methods to filter in Google BigQuery. (Say Table2 is small.) Which method of filtering would be preferable, and why? Does it depend on the size of table1? Or is there another, better method?

```
SELECT
  a.ID
FROM
  table1 AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  table2 AS b
ON
  a.ID = b.ID
WHERE 
  b.ID is NULL
```

or

```
SELECT
  ID
FROM
  table1
WHERE
  ID NOT IN (
    SELECT
      ID
    FROM
      table2)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Second is limited to one and only one field to be filtered by.

First can be used to filter by multiple fields, like below

```
SELECT
  a.ID
FROM
  table1 AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  table2 AS b
ON
  a.ID = b.ID AND a.Field2 = b.Field2 AND a.Field3 = b.Field3
WHERE 
  b.ID is NULL
```

Comment: Very true. But do you have any ideas how the performance of the 2 methods compare?

Comment: never did benchmarking of these for BigQuery. I think it is because intuitively i would always think of join version here to be a winner. I think also, that subquery version is anyway translated to join during execution and might by just shortcut for when only one filed to join. Btw, recently Google Team introduced Query Plan Explanation - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation - so you can try and see it on your own

Answer (score 5):

I tested a two fields anti-join and the difference was noticeable.

```
SELECT fields, ..
FROM inputA A
LEFT JOIN inputB B
  ON A.key = B.key AND A.key2 = B.key2
WHERE B.key IS NULL AND B.key2 IS NULL
```

Performs better than its NOT IN equivalent:

```
SELECT fields, ..
FROM inputA A
WHERE key NOT IN (SELECT NUM_RUT FROM key)
  AND key2 NOT IN (SELECT key2 FROM inputB)
```

in this case 5s vs 7s in BigQuery after reading 4.6Gb.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is always the way to query a database, just to expand on what was said by Mikhail you can also add AND under Where for example.

```
SELECT
  a.ID
FROM
  table1 AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  table2 AS b
ON
  a.ID = b.ID AND a.Field2 = b.Field2 AND a.Field3 = b.Field3
WHERE 
  b.ID is NULL AND a.id=75
```

also if you use SELECT DISTINCT at the start of your query it will only return distinct values (this will stop it returning the same item more than once)